# Get all records except some array using Active Record in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

There is the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
end

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user
end
```

I need to get all `cities` which has not associated `user`. I know how I can get all cities which has associated `user`:

```
City.joins(:user)
```

But how can I get all `cities` except the result of `City.joins`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good question.. +1.. Thinking!

Comment: I agree with Arup simple but Good +1 from me please use `arel` for good and understandable code :))

Comment: A good solution would be to left outer join and group on user count, then selecting count as 0. I'm working on it atm :)

Comment: @Logar `City.joins(:user)` is <strike>left outer join only</strike>, btw. *how can I get all cities except the result of City.joins?* Stopped me.. :)

Comment: this is a bad way to load all the cities using `City.all` best use `joins` or `includes`

Comment: @Logar Yeap!... :) Mistake

Answer (score 4):

You should use LEFT OUTER JOIN. Instead of throw out "cities" without "users" from result (like INNER JOIN), it will nullify all fields from "users" table.

```
City
.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON cities.id = users.city_id')
.where('users.id IS NULL')
```

Comment: Yes, i was looking for a group and count, but your solution seems more simple !

Answer (score 2):

One more way :

```
City.where.not(id: User.pluck('distinct city_id'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with this

```
City.where('id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(city_id) FROM users)')
```

Comment: I was thinking the same.. :_)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user
end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :city
end   

User.where(city_id: nil)
```

All the users who does not assoc with city

Now all cities without users

```
City.joins(:user).where(user: {id: nil})
```

Using Arel

```
cities = Arel::Table.new(:cities)
users  = Arel::Table.new(:users)


cities.joins(:users).where(users[:id].eq(nil))
```

Comment: I need to get cities, not Users

Answer (score 0):

Well, It's probably not the best solution but you could do something like :

`City.all - City.joins(:user)`

Answer (score 0):

Basically, and without context, what you are asking is :

With a = City.all and b = City.joins(:user)

```
> a = %w( 1 2 3 4 )
=> ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
> b = %w( 2 3 )
=> ["2", "3"]
> a - b
=> ["1", "4"]
```

Again, this is strictly what you want to do, array-wise, not what you **should do** considering your context

Comment: Ok thanks, but what I should do? I need to get cities without users in order to create a new user with free city :)

Comment: How your answer differs from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28672258/2767755) ? :-)

Comment: @malcoauri : You will get an array of cities without users with that. But for your case, I think you should follow yevhene way of doing it :)

Answer (score -1):

Since the City doesn't have a foreign key you can use

```
City.where.not(User.pluck('DISTINCT city_id))
```

References: [pluck](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck) and [where not](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/WhereChain.html#method-i-not)

Comment: `City.where(user: nil)` is same as `City.where(user_id: nil)`.. But `City` doesn't have the column `user_id`.. :)

Comment: @PauloFidalgo  That's too _ugly_ :p